# visual basic array case statement

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba, case

I'm new to visual basic and have been using vb.net to create a console/text based game. I want to make my game a little bit more "smart". The idea I've had to do this is to create an array of synonyms for yes and an array of synonyms for no, and similar arrays for over words. I intended on using a case statement with the array to decide weather the users input was a synonym for yes or for no. I have had no luck so far, and I was wondering if anybody here knew how it can be done or if I'm barking up the wrong tree. Maybe there is a different way for me to approach this?

My Select attempt:

```
Select Case userInput
    Case yes(0) To yes(34)
        Console.WriteLine("you said something like yes, you said {0}", userInput)

End Select
```

The start of my array: (there are 34 synonyms so far)

```
Dim yes(0 To 34) As String

yes(0) = "yes"
yes(1) = "ok"
yes(2) = "yep"
yes(3) = "yeah"
```

If anybody can help me it would be very much appreciated :) Thank you very much!

Comment: I haven't done VB in a long time, but I don't know if the variable case statement values are going to work. I might do someting like "if (IsYes(userInput)) elseif (IsNo(userInput)), then just write little functions to look the the lists of words.

Comment: Select...Case Statements, expression1 To expression2. The value of expression1 must be less than or equal to the value of expression2. Like: Case "yes" To "yesss"

Comment: Thank you! This has pointed me in the right direction. Can't wait to get started now! I love it when you get excited for a little project of your own :)

Comment: I have it working, I created a function that accepts a string, it the uses a small If statement to Return True if the user input is found within my array of synonyms for yes (I use .Contains(userInput) to search the array). Now to make an array for no. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to use a `Select Case` for this purpose. A simple `List(Of T).Contains` can do the trick. Then you can go ahead to put it in a function so you can call it several times in your application.

Sample Code:

```
Public Enum Answer
    Yes
    No
    Other
End Enum

Public Function GetAnswer(answer As String) As Answer
    Static yesAnswers = New List(Of String)({"yes", "yeah", "yep", "aye"})
    Static noAnswers = New List(Of String)({"no", "nope", "nay"})

    If yesAnswers.Contains(answer.ToLower()) Then
        Return Answer.Yes
    ElseIf noAnswers.Contains(answer.ToLower()) Then
        Return Answer.No
    Else
        Return Answer.Cancel
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

I would create a translation dictionary

```
Dim translations As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

translations.Add("yes", "yes")
translations.Add("ok", "yes")
translations.Add("yep", "yes")
translations.Add("yeah", "yes")

translations.Add("no", "no")
translations.Add("nope", "no")
```

With these definitions you can get the standard version of an answer very easily

```
Dim userInput = "yeah"
Dim response As String = Nothing

translations.TryGetValue(userInput, response)
Select Case response
    Case "yes"
        Console.WriteLine("ok")
    Case "no"
        Console.WriteLine("cancel")
    Case Else
        Console.WriteLine("rubbish!")
End Select
```

Dictionaries have the fastest lookup times.